# this code is not printing anything on the serial moniter. the code is in setup()

Tags: arduino-uno

```
Serial.println("CLEARDATA"); //clears up any data left from previous projects
Serial.println("LABEL,time,load reading(gm),microwave output,CO sensor,sound data,magnetic sensor "); //always write LABEL, so excel knows the next things will be the names of the columns (instead of Acolumn you could write Time for instance)
Serial.println("RESETTIMER"); //resets timer to 0

//pinMode(AOUTpin, INPUT);//sets the pin as an input to the arduino 
// pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);//sets the pin as an output of the arduino 
Serial.println("HX711 calibration sketch");
Serial.println("Remove all weight from scale");
Serial.println("After readings begin, place known weight on scale");
Serial.println("Press + or a to increase calibration factor");
Serial.println("Press - or z to decrease calibration factor");
```

Comment: Please include the entire setup() function.

Comment: Serial.begin(9600); is missing

Answer (score 4):

There can be different reasons, among:

- The speed of the serial port does not match with the serial 'monitor'
- The speed of the serial port is not set at all (can cause first problem)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see this before the print statements:
Serial.begin(9600); // or some other speed

That will prevent anything from printing.